# Keycloak fails to start in docker compose "no such file or directory: unknown"

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak

When the docker compose.yaml below is started postgres starts but the keycloak fails with the following output.

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh ": stat /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh : no such file or directory: unknown
```

If I enable interactive terminal in the `compose.yaml`, change the ENTRYPOINT to `bash` and manually execute `/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev`, Keycloak starts up properly.

I have tried making the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile `/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev` and removing command from the `compose.yaml` with the same results.

Any suggestions on what I am doing incorrectly?

---

Dockerfile for keycloak (from their site) with my jdbc URL, username and password

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=postgres

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:keycloak,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# change these values to point to a running postgres instance
ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://snc-postgres:5432/keycloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=localdevuser
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=password1
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=keycloak
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh "]
```

compose.yaml

```
name: snc-infrastructure
services:
  snc-postgres:
    image: me/postgres
    secrets:
      - db-password
    build:
      context: ./postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      tags:
        - "me/postgres:latest"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-U", "localdevuser", "-d", "keycloak" ]
      interval: 10s
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: postgres-snc
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - snc-network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db-password
    container_name: snc-postgres
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5432
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host

  snc-keycloak:
    image: me/keycloak:latest
    build:
      context: ./keycloak
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      tags:
        - "me/keycloak:latest"
    #    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    #    tty: true        # docker run -t
    depends_on:
      snc-postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command:
      - start-dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8001:8001"
    networks:
      - snc-network

volumes:
  postgres-snc:
    name: postgres-snc

secrets:
  db-password:
    file: ./postgres/password.txt

networks:
  snc-network:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional space in your `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh "]
                                    ☝️
```

should be

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

Kindly, from [Cloud-IAM](https://www.cloud-iam.com)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  That was it!  "For want of a nail ..." or in this case 3 hours of life lost to an extra space.